# Fastest way to load eager loaded associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Contract` which belongs to a `Provider`, and I am doing this:

```
@contracts = Contract.where(provider_id: provider_ids).includes(:provider)
```

And I want to get the distinct providers:

```
@providers = @contracts.map(&:provider).uniq
```

Is there a way to make DB do all the work? i.e. map is making Ruby work.

Comment: I think it does fetch distinct data, won't it? `select * from providers where id in (1,2,3)`? Then they are cached to be called via contracts' objects. or I am misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

why not to do this

```
 Provider.find Contract.select("distinct provider_id")
```

Comment: I need contracts too.

Comment: `@contracts = Contract.includes(:provider)` i think this gives all contracts. do you need all contacts ? if so, it is fine to do this in ruby instead of database as all data is already in memory.

Comment: I don't need all contracts, I am actually doing `Contract.where(provider_id: provider_ids).includes(:provider)`